# How to translate hardware ascii to hardware scan code in win32

Tags: windows, visual-studio, winapi

Is there a way to translate a character to its corresponding hardware scan code (not the virtual key code)? I need that to communicate with ancient hardware device.

Comment: Which ancient hardware device??

Comment: An old homemade embedded system. It accepts raw keyboard scan-codes sent to it. I made a C# application to control it, and I want data sent to it readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems the most direct method would be to use MapVirtualKey or MapVirtualKeyEx which translates from VK-codes to Scan codes.

The character to VK scan code can be gotten using VkKeyScan (extracting the low byte which contains the VK Code according to MS documentation). So to get the scan code of 'X':

```
 UINT VKCode=LOBYTE(VkKeyScan('X'));
 UINT ScanCode=MapVirtualKey(VKCode,0);
```

Comment: A more complete answer is, to use VkKeyScan to convert the key to the virtualkeycode, and then with MapVirtualKey convert it to the scancode

Comment: Actually tried this in real life and then had problems; after rereading the MS docs I added the  LOBYTE to the solution code above